# Lightweight Active Directory Monitoring/Auditing users, groups and group policy

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, audit-logging, domaincontroller

My team has attempted to utilize a 3rd party Active Directory Object auditing tool which ran some automated scripts and turned on active directory auditing on our domain controllers. We use Win 2016 Server for our domain controllers.

As a result our DCs got bogged down and we subsequently turned off the auditing. My boss doesn't want to risk having this happen again so I am attempting to find a less invasive way to monitor changes to groups, user accounts and group policy. For security reasons, we want to be able to ask the question: Who changed what and at what date and time.

My options as I see them are basically some kind of custom .NET library or solution, accessing LDAP via PHP or perhaps a polling solution using PowerShell to dump data to a secondary file, API or service.

I've scoured the internet for a solution that might work for us and spent several days experimenting and building prototypes to no avail. It seems that the expectation for all possible solutions are to turn on the auditing features and simply hope that your DCs don't immediately max out on resources.

If we were to deploy a test DC and turn on auditing for evaluation purposes, I could potentially come up with a solution to track changes over time but we wouldn't be able to assess the real world impact of certain auditing features being turned on because it wouldn't have the same traffic that our production Domain Controllers have.

The solution that I am looking for has a low impact on the performance of our domain controllers and offers a method by which to store data pertaining to active directory object changes that can be subsequently displayed on one or more reports.

Comment: The solution _is_ to turn on auditing ACEs (you don't have to enable auditing of _everything at once_ - review the audit policy settings in your Default DC policy and enable subcategories one-by-one in steps). Beyond that, it's just a question of [capacity management](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14355.capacity-planning-for-active-directory-domain-services.aspx)

Comment: What level of auditing was enabled?
Can you document and post the steps taken to enable auditing?
Was auditing on all objects enabled or was auditing properly tuned to create events only for those object types within the appropriate OUs?
Are you using any kind of SIEM or log aggregator?

Comment: It is my understanding that enough comprehensive auditing was turned on to instantly create performance issues, thanks for your response, however I don't know exactly what was enabled just that much of the auditing features were enabled .. the product was netwrix.